# monaco-editor-webpack-plugin loads all features

Tags: reactjs, webpack, monaco-editor, react-app-rewired

I'm using `react-app-rewired` in my React app, I added the plugin for Monaco Editor, and I'm trying to reduce the amount of features.
I tried multiple steps, but nothing worked.

This is the configuration I added for testing:

```
new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
  languages: ['json'],
  features: ['rename'],
})
```

This should only compile the rename feature, but after running analyzer on the build folder I get that all the features were loaded:
[The analyzed bundle for MonacoEditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwdOh.png)

I tried other stuff too, the bundle size remained the same no matter what I did, am I missing something?

Comment: Did you manage to get it working?